# JS Разделение строк с помощью RegEXP

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, split

Помогите пожалуйста, делаю свой редактор и не могу правильно построить регулярку чтобы она делила текст по блочно;

```
arrayList = ['text','[bold]test[/bold]','[size args="1px"][/size]', etc...]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можно детальнее что и как она должна делить?

Comment: Есть у меня текст который содержит блоки "Какой то текст [href="ссылка"][/href]", я парсю всё содержимое и заменяю на html код, ну и вывожу на экран готовый документ, крч недо Wysiwyg.
Нужно разбить текст в массив чтобы каждый найденный блок был в собственном элементе массива "[bold]text[/bod]"

Answer (score 0):

```
const re = /(\[[^\]]{1,}\][^\[]{1,}\[\/[^\]]{1,}\]|\s+.{1,})/gi

const str = `
[italic]Random italic text[/italic]
[bold]Random bold text[/bold]    

random text
[blabla]][]
random text 2
[href="https://example.com"]Random link[/href="https://example.com"]
`

console.log(str.match(re))
// [ "\n[italic]Random italic text[/italic]", "\n[bold]Random bold text[/bold]    ", "\n\nrandom text", "\n[blabla]][]", "\nrandom text 2", "\n[href=\"https://example.com\"]Random link[/href=\"https://example.com\"]" ]
```